# Cannot enable e-mail alerts in Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have been trying to get e-mail alerts to work in TFS 2012. I have configured it in the Admin console and tried from the command line using tfsconfig.exe.

When i run the tfsconfig.exe command it will tell me it had enabled the alerts, but then you run it with out any parameters it says they are disabled.

This is running on windows 2012 server.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can try checking whether your firewall allows connections between TFS and your SMTP server. If it doesn't help, check that the service account for TFS has permission to send emails and your SMTP allows anonymous emails sending. Otherwise you can create special mailing account for alerts.

You can also look the instructions here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx) and accepted answer to the similar problem here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/tfsadmin/thread/d373b3e5-95f4-40c0-980a-fc8f6143efe2).